# Are porins on the inner or on the outer membrane of mitochondria?

Tags: mitochondria

I've looked at multiple resources and they are saying different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not my field, but The [Transporter Classification Database](http://www.tcdb.org/search/result.php?tc=1.B.8) would appear to be a reliable source and states that:

> The best characterized members of the MPP family are the voltage-dependent anion-selective channel (VDAC) porins in the **mitochondrial outer membrane.**

Searching through the Protein Data Bank one can find a crystal structure for human voltage-dependent anion channel 1 and the [associated paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/wol1/doi/10.1002/pro.3211/full) also states that it is in the outer mitochondrial membrane, so you would imagine that they should know.